# Drawing points on an image with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Given:

- A set of points arranged in a tensor of shape `[batch_size, num_points, 2]`,
- And a batch of images of shape `[batch_size, height, width, 3]`,

how can we draw the points on the image?

There is `tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes` to draw bounding box on top of the image pixels but I did not find an equivalent for drawing key points.

A tensorflow-nic answer that would not require the use of pure python with `tf.py_func` would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I use boxes with zero size to draw points:

```
def draw_points(images, points, tf_summary_writer, step):
    """
    :param images: [batch_size, height, width, 3], tf.float32, from 0 to 1
    :param points: [batch_size, num_points, 2], tf.float32, from 0 to 1
    :param tf_summary_writer: SummaryWriter
    :param step: int
    """
    with tf_summary_writer.as_default():
        x_min = points[:, :, 0]  # shape [bs, np]
        y_min = points[:, :, 1]  # shape [bs, np]
        x_max = points[:, :, 0]  # shape [bs, np]
        y_max = points[:, :, 1]  # shape [bs, np]
        boxes = tf.stack([y_min, x_min, y_max, x_max], axis=-1)  # shape [bs, np, 4]
        image_with_points = tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(images, boxes, colors=[[1, 0, 0, 1]])  # RGBA red color
        tf.summary.image('points', image_with_points, step)
```